# Capitalize city name from database with ucfirst in php?

Tags: php, ucfirst

is it possible to make the {CITY} output to be capitalized with for example ucfirst? Can this code be altered in some way to make it capitalized?

```
<?php   
$city_meta = get_option('city_meta' );
$city_description = get_option('city_description' );
$default_api = get_option('default_api' );

/* Update Settings */
if(isset($_POST['submit_changes'])){ 
    update_option('city_meta',$_POST['city_meta']);
    update_option('city_description',$_POST['city_description']);

    $info =weatherCity::getCities();
    //$info =array_slice($info, 0, 3);  
    $sr=0;
    foreach($info as $key=>$value):
        $postTitle = 'Väder '.$value->name;
        global $wpdb;
        $pageInfo=$wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID FROM `".$wpdb->prefix."posts` WHERE post_title = '" . $postTitle . "' AND `post_type`='page' ");

        if(!empty($pageInfo)):  

            $metaTitle=$_POST['city_meta'];
            $metaDesc=$_POST['city_description'];

            $metaTitle=str_replace('{CITY}',$value->name,$metaTitle);
            $metaDesc=str_replace('{CITY}',$value->name,$metaDesc);

            update_post_meta($pageInfo->ID,'_yoast_wpseo_title',$metaTitle);
            update_post_meta($pageInfo->ID,'_yoast_wpseo_metadesc',$metaDesc);

            $sr++;
        endif;
    endforeach;



    set_error_message( _e('City Meta Settings has been updated succesfully','weather'),'0');
    foreceRedirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=city_meta') );
    exit;
}

?>
```

Would be great if someone could find a simple solution for this. :-)

Comment: Sure .. but you're not going to get proper looking city names, ex: `"New york"`?

Comment: `Rio de janeiro`, `La paz`, `N'djamena`, `Addis ababa`, `Port au prince`, `Kuwait city`, `Kuala lumpur`, `Port of spain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ucwords()

```
$metaTitle=ucwords(str_replace('{CITY}',$value->name,$metaTitle));
$metaDesc=ucwords(str_replace('{CITY}',$value->name,$metaDesc));
```

This will uppercase the first character of each word in a string.

PHP.Net link

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using ucwords, this fixed it in combination with dotkomm's reply

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @dotkomm and @Harvey Fletcher it was a combination of your answeres that fixed the issue.

Solution looks like this:

```
$metaTitle=str_replace('{CITY}', ucwords($value->name),$metaTitle);
$metaDesc=str_replace('{CITY}', ucwords($value->name),$metaDesc);
```

Comment: Nice! Please could you (if you have enough reputation to), upvote our answers to show your thanks? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately my rep is to low =(

Answer (score 0):

There are several Methods, the most elegant way in my opinion would be doing it with css text-transform property capitalize `text-transform: capitalize;` as it is not altering the data

But yes `ucfirst()` should also do the job, but here the data would be altered for further processing

Also you could do the job inside the mysql query

In your example, if you want to use `ucfirst()` you should replace the line

```
  $metaTitle=str_replace('{CITY}',$value->name,$metaTitle);
  $metaDesc=str_replace('{CITY}',$value->name,$metaDesc);
```

with

```
 $metaTitle=str_replace('{CITY}', ucfirst($value->name),$metaTitle);
 $metaDesc=str_replace('{CITY}', ucfirst($value->name),$metaDesc);
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed it with your second example but changed ucfirst() to ucwords()